# 10 different domain names with 2 php files only database query changes

Tags: php, mysql, dns, names

i have 10 domain names which has 2 php files index.php, inside.php
only query changes as per site id 
right now i am uploading 2 pages through ftp to 10 sites

is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same document root for all domains, and in your PHP script check `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` to determine which hostname is used.

Comment: can you provide some example in detail?

is this possible on shared server ?

Comment: Simply point all those domains to the same IP address in your DNS setup. Within your webserver, configure it to serve one of the domains as the "real" site, and the rest of the domains as aliases. Within the PHP script, the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will contain the name of the site as the user entered it, from which you can decide how to change your content as needed for each of the domains.

Comment: i have 10 domain names which will point to 1 directory but for all 10 domain names content will be different. will this affect google or other search engine ranking?

Comment: No, it will not affect your Google ranking. For visitors and Google, it is not visible that all domains are served from the same directory.

Comment: creating multiple domain aliases - is it possible on shared server ? or do i have to buy VPS solution for the same which is bit expensive?